# Mosaic data looks like checkerboard using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic, arcgis-10.6

I have copied mosaic data from the external disk to the local disk. When I try to load the mosaic data into a new ArcMap document, it is displayed as a checkerboard. But if I first load the mosaic data from the external disk and then the mosaic from the local disk, the mosaic from the local disk is also displayed correctly.

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

When i use ArcCatalog , and then use the repair path (or i have tried tool repair mosaic dataset in ArcMap) the old path is the one that is on internal drive

Comment: Try to rebuild overviews for the mosaic.  It probably has information about the overviews for the original location, but not for the current location.

Comment: PS.  And don't use the default "Nearest" method... often produces buggy results (in some versions of ArcMap).  Cubic is best.